# MYSQL Command To get column headers, where, and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, plotly

So I want to export from my database table to a .csv file to work with, but my problem is getting all the follow parameters right.

> 1. First, I need to export all the column headers as the first column in the csv file,
> 2. then from there I need to export all the data that I need using (WHERE ...) and
> 3. finally I need to order a certain column (ORDER BY ...).

Currently, I can only get two of the 3 parameters correct.
So my current statement is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( " ... all my rows names" 
       UNION ALL 
       ( SELECT * 
         from table_name 
         where Set_Type = "..." or ID = "..." ORDER by probability 
       )
     ) as tbl INTO OUTFILE '   ' FIELDS TERMINATED by ',';
```

So currently, that command gets the columns into the first row and the WHERE Set_Type or ID part correct. However, it won't sort the probability part. Is there a way I can do everything before exporting? Preferably in one command, but if it's multiple commands, what I'm doing requires a certain ID every time so the command will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link has a nice explanation:

[How to save a MySql query with headers](https://database.guide/how-to-save-a-mysql-query-result-to-a-csv-file/)

But so that you don't have to visit the site, the example they give is:

> To include the column names (so that the .CSV file contains headers on the first line), you can hardcode them in another SELECT statement, prepended to the rest of the query by a UNION ALL operator.

```
/* Add column headers */
SELECT 'OrderId','CustomerID','EmployeeID','OrderDate','RequiredDate','ShippedDate','ShipVia','Freight','ShipName','ShipAddress','ShipCity','ShipRegion','ShipPostalCode','ShipCountry','OrderID','ProductId','UnitPrice','Quantity','Discount'

UNION ALL

/* Now the actual query */
SELECT o.OrderId, o.CustomerID, o.EmployeeID, o.OrderDate, o.RequiredDate, o.ShippedDate, o.ShipVia, o.Freight, o.ShipName, o.ShipAddress, o.ShipCity, o.ShipRegion, o.ShipPostalCode, o.ShipCountry, od.OrderID, od.ProductId, od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity, od.Discount 

FROM `Orders` o  LEFT JOIN `Order Details` od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 

/* Save the query results to a file */
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Basically, select the headers seperately and use UNION ALL. Just add the Order by to the section of the query where you actually fetch your data.

### Example

So this example works for me. The reason you were getting the headers at the bottom was because you were applying the ORDER BY clause to the entire UNION. You need to wrap the second part of the UNION in brackets to only apply the ORDER BY to everything inside the brackets.

This works for me:

```
SELECT 'ID', 'Name', 'Description'

UNION ALL 

(SELECT id, name, description

FROM test.questions

ORDER BY name Asc

LIMIT 9999);
```

A little more information from MYSQL site:

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.

Basically, you MUST also apply a LIMIT when applying an ORDER BY else it won't take affect.

Comment: before I try, just a simple question. What is the o in the o.OrderId? Is that just the database name or something else?

Comment: it doesn't work. This method gets the order by and the where but the column headers are at the end of the csv file.

Comment: Yes, o was the table alias and I have added an example to show why your columns where at the end.